# How do I write a java method that adds the digits of each number in a string

Tags: java

I am working on a challenge that requires us to input a string containing numbers. For example, "This 23 string has 738 numbers"

And the method needs to add the values of 2+3 to return 5 and 7+3+8 to return 18.

But I don't know how to make a loop to find each number in the input string, perform that operation, and continue through the rest of the string. Any suggestions or solutions?

A successful method would take a string as an input, like "This 23 string has 34 or cat 48", and the method would return 5, 7 and 12.

I have figured out how to use regular expressions to tease out the numbers from a string, but I don't know how to add the digits of each number teased out into an output

package reverseTest;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExtractNumbers {`enter code here`
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          String str;
          String numbers;

          Scanner SC=new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.print("Enter string that contains numbers: ");
          str=SC.nextLine();

          //extracting string
          numbers=str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

          System.out.println("Numbers are: " + numbers);
      }
}
```

And this adds ALL the numbers in a string:

```
String a="jklmn489pjro635ops";

    int sum = 0;

    String num = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if(Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i))) {
            num = num + a.charAt(i);
        } else {
            if(!num.equals("")) {
                sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(num);
                num = "";
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

I don't know how to combine this code with code that can add the numbers this method outputs together.

Comment: when you do replaceAll with this regex you're also replacing the spaces with empty string so this string: "This 23 string has 738 numbers" will turn to: "23738" and you won't be able to know where the first number ended and the next begins. Don't replace the spaces as a first step, then split the string on spaces and parse each number separately. From there it should not be very difficult to achieve your goal.

Comment: Do you need some code to get the numbers in the text or do you need to know how to combine both codes?

Comment: show a minimized section of your code

Comment: I think the first bit of code extracts the numbers. I need code to take those numbers and add the digits of them together and return those values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just turn the second bit of code into a function, and call it on your System input reading call of the first?

Answer (score 4):

We can try using Java's regex engine with the pattern `\d+`.  Then we can iterate each match character by character, and tally the sum.

```
String a = "This 23 string has 738 numbers";
String pattern = "\\d+";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(a);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.print("found numbers: " + m.group(0) + " = ");
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < m.group(0).length(); ++i) {
        sum += m.group(0).charAt(i) - '0';
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

This prints:

```
found numbers: 23 = 5
found numbers: 738 = 18
```

Comment: but he say:"A successful method would take a string as an input, like "This 23 string has 34 or cat 48", and the method would return 5, 7 and 12." so in "jklmn489pjro635ops" should return 21 and 14 no?

Comment: @DrPepper Thanks for pointing that out.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `split` the input string to have separated tokens and then `split` each token to have only digits:

```
String s = "This 23 string has 738 numbers";
String[] st = s.split(" ");
for (int i=0 ; i<st.length ; i++) {
    if (st[i].matches("[0-9]+")) {
        String[] c = st[i].split("(?=\\d)");
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j=0 ; j<c.length ; j++) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(c[j]);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

the output is:

```
5
18
```

Comment: adfsadsfsddasdf

Answer (score 1):

I'm re-learning Java after a two decade hiatus, and evaluating BlueJ at the same time for possible use in my classroom.  This seemed like a great project to practice with, so thanks for the post!  Here's my take on it, without the use of Regular Expressions.

Class FindDigits:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class FindDigits
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter string to analyze: ");
        String input = scan.nextLine();

        FindDigits fd = new FindDigits(input);
        System.out.println("Input: " + fd.getInput());
        List<NumberSum> results = fd.getSums();
        if (results.size() > 0)
        {
            for(NumberSum ns: results)
            {
                System.out.println("Number: " + ns.getNumber() + ", Sum: " + ns.getSum());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No numbers found.");
        }
    }

    private String _input;
    public String getInput()
    {
        return _input;
    }

    public FindDigits(String input)
    {
        _input = input;
    }

    private List<String> getNumbers()
    {
        List<String> numbers = new ArrayList();
        String curNumber = "";
        for(Character c: getInput().toCharArray())
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                curNumber = curNumber + c;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!curNumber.isEmpty())
                {
                    numbers.add(curNumber);
                    curNumber = "";
                }
            }
        }
        if (!curNumber.isEmpty())
        {
            numbers.add(curNumber);
        }
        return numbers;
    }

    public List<NumberSum> getSums()
    {
        List<NumberSum> sums = new ArrayList<NumberSum>();
        for(String number: getNumbers())
        {
            sums.add(new NumberSum(number));
        }
        return sums;
    }

}
```

Class NumberSum:

```
public class NumberSum
{

        private String _number;
        public String getNumber()
        {
            return _number;
        }

        public NumberSum(String number)
        {
            _number = number;
            for(char c: number.toCharArray())
            {
                if(!Character.isDigit(c))
                {
                    _number = "";
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public int getSum()
        {
            return sum(getNumber());
        }

        private int sum(String number)
        {
            if (!getNumber().isEmpty())
            {
                int total = 0;
                for(char c: number.toCharArray())
                {
                    total = total + Character.getNumericValue(c);
                }
                return total;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;   
            }
        }

}
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Use `! .equals` instead of `!=` for String comparison.

Comment: @Robert Thanks!  So, for example, `!getNumber().equals("")`?  Gonna take awhile to go back and forth between Java and .Net without making mistakes.

Comment: @Robert Switched to using `isEmpty()` instead.