# Add Start and Stop point parameters to method that adds sums of numbers in a string

Tags: java

I am trying to modify a method from the post marked as duplicate that will allow me to enter a string containing numbers, like "Here are77 with88 monsters" which I adds the sum of the numbers in the string to return 14 and 16 if I evaluated the entire string. How would I enhance this method to evaluate start and stop points in the string? So if I wanted to evaluate position 3 through 10, it would return just 14, since 77 are numbers between positions 3 and 10?

I have done quite a bit of research, but I'm really new to Java, and don't know enough yet to figure this out. The code below is where I'm at now:

```
    String s = "Here are77 with 88 monsters";
    String[] st = s.split(" ");
    for (int i=0 ; i<st.length ; i++) {
        if (st[i].matches("[0-9]+")) {
            String[] c = st[i].split("(?=\\d)");
            int sum = 0;
            for(int j=0 ; j<c.length ; j++) {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(c[j]);
            }
          return sum;} 
        }
```

I need help to add the two extra position parameters so I can use this code above to calculate the sum of the digits within those margins in a method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a java method that adds the digits of each number in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56310522/how-do-i-write-a-java-method-that-adds-the-digits-of-each-number-in-a-string)

Comment: I really appreciate any feedback. I'm trying to identify how to implement start and stop points in the array to accomplish the output in the related post.

Comment: Using the code YOU posted in your previous question...you can determine start/stop points by iterating over the string and asking if each character is a digit with the Character.isDigit() function.

Comment: Also in your PAQ, take a look at the getNumbers() function in my post.  It finds all the numbers and returns them in a List.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual code doesn't work well, and the possible duplicate is far too complicated.

---

1. Sum digits in a `String`

   - remove all chars that are not digits
   - split them individually
   - parse and sum them

     ```
     static int sumstring(String s) {
         String[] st = s.replaceAll("\\D", "").split("");
         int sum = 0;
         for (String digit : st) {
             sum += Integer.parseInt(digit);
         }
         return sum;
     }
     ```
2. Sum digits in a `String`, with start and stop

   - way **1.** and add `substring()` method

     ```
     static int sumstring(String s, int start, int stop) {
         s = s.substring(start, stop);
         String[] st = s.replaceAll("\\D", "").split("");
         int sum = 0;
         for (String digit : st) {
             sum += Integer.parseInt(digit);
         }
         return sum;
     }
     ```

---

3. To get an array of the sums (each number):

   ```
   static int[] sumstring(String s) {
       String[] st = s.replaceAll("\\D", " ").trim().split("\\s+");
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(st));
       int[] sums = new int[st.length];
       for (int i = 0; i < sums.length; i++) {
           int sum = 0;
           for (String digit : st[i].split("")) {
               sum += Integer.parseInt(digit);
           }
           sums[i] = sum;
       }
       return sums;
   }
   ```

---

4. Replace number bu sum of its digits

   ```
   static String sumstring(String s) {
       String[] st = s.split("\\s+");
       for (int i = 0; i < st.length; i++) {
           String word = st[i];
           if (word.matches("^[0-9]+$")) {
               int sum = 0;
               for (String digit : word.split("")) {
                   sum += Integer.parseInt(digit);
               }
               st[i] = "" + sum;
           }
       }
       return String.join(" ", st);
   }
   ```

Comment: I think he wants the function to return an array of ints with all the sums of following numbers, as he said his example should return 14 (7+7) and 16 (8+8). Maybe I understood things wrong though.

Comment: How would you do what you have added (and coded much better) and keep any characters also? So if I entered "I77 have 2 bears" and wanted to evaluate from 1 - 9, it would return "14 have 2"?

Comment: I'm probably making this too complicated, but is a solution to parse out the numbers' additions, maintain their position, and then parse out characters and merge the two together somehow? (I'm just barely starting to learn how regular expressions work)

Comment: Thanks JohnDarls. And thank you all so much for your expertise.

Comment: @JohnDarls np, you can now think about vote up/accept the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my code from your previous post boiled down to its bare essentials:

```
public class AddDigitsInString
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input = "Here are77 with 88 monsters";
        System.out.println("Input: " + input);

        String curNumber = "";
        for(Character c: input.toCharArray())
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                curNumber = curNumber + c;
            }
            else
            {
                if (curNumber != "")
                {
                    int curSum = sum(curNumber);
                    System.out.println("Number: " + curNumber + ", Sum: " + curSum);
                    curNumber = "";
                }
            }
        }
        if (curNumber != "")
        {
            int curSum = sum(curNumber);
            System.out.println("Number: " + curNumber + ", Sum: " + curSum);
        }
    }


    public static int sum(String number)
    {
        int total = 0;
        for(char c: number.toCharArray())
        {
            total = total + Character.getNumericValue(c);
        }
        return total;
    }

}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You are a great teacher Idle_Mind. I hope to pay it forward with as much as you have helped. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't your loop have dead code on i++? Since you will be returning out as soon as your first iteration is done.